# Stop Eclipse from autocompleting

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Eclipse has suddenly started doing something weird and has become unusable. I'm using the PyDev editor.

When I type a regular letter, for example, t, and then Enter, Eclipse changes it to a complete word. In the case of t, it becomes "TabError". A becomes "And", b becomes "break" and so on.

It just suddenly started happening as I was typing in the editor. I don't know what combination of keys I must have pressed to start this behavior. I've tried restarting my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the behaviour has changed for you, however what you are describing is behaviour as expected in the PyDev editor, i.e. if I have:

```
import time
t
```

and my cursor is just after the `t`, then I see auto completions pop-up and if I press Enter the selected completion is inserted. Here is a screenshot just after I typed t:

[image: autocomplete]

The screenshot in @aleroot's answer documents this with *Note: Enter will always apply the completion*, further recommending *Note: Shift-Enter can be used if you want a new line without applying a completion*. These same notes apply to editing Java code in the Java Editors

So what you are seeing is intended behaviour.

However, you may not like such autocompletions, so I recommend tuning them. In particular, you probably want to turn off *Request completion on all letter chars and '_'?* Making this change will more closely match the default behaviour in the Java editor which by default automatically shows completions only on <kbd>.</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

To tweak those preferences you have to go to :

Preferences->PyDev->Editor->Code Completion

[image]

Comment: But what could have suddenly made it start doing this? I didn't change any preferences. I'm thinking that it's not a preference issue per se. In any case, I tried unchecking "Use code completion" and the issue is still there. In any case, it says "ENTER will always apply the completion"

Comment: Are you sure then that is not something like a service of the OS that is doing that ?

Comment: It's not happening in other editors (Notepad++, HeidiSQL)

Comment: Try creating another workspace then, you will reset every setting to default